# Mongodb search key /attrinute having space

Tags: mongodb

I have thousands of items in my gameItem collection with the following as example.

```
{
    "weapon name 1":{price:01},
    "weapon name 2":{price:100}
}
```

and I run a query like so in shell

```
db.gameItems.find({"weapon name 1":{$exists:1}})
```

nothing returns but it works when my keys don't have spaces...

First questions: Is there a way to search key values with spaces?
Second question: Should I change my data model to be like so?:

```
   {
      weapon:{name: "weapon name 1", price:01}
      weapon:{name: "weapon name 2", price:100}
   }
```

And then add an index to the weapon name field? Does this increase search performance with only 2 fields in each weapon document?

Thanks

Edit:

Apologies, it appears the db collection gameItems actually looks like this...

```
{
   last_updated:"2016-04-01",
   items:{
          "weapon name 1":{price:01},
          "weapon name 2":{price:100}
   }
}
```

so how would I search for them inside the item document?

Comment: The way you propose to reshape your schema is almost correct. Price has to be numeric, it seems, but 01 doesn't seem correct. If you search by weapon.name often, adding an index would greatly improve performance.

Comment: This works fine with me, are you sure you are querying the right collection? In your statement you imply you have a `gameItem` collection but your query is against the `gameItems` collection?

Comment: I made a mistake. I updated the OP

Answer (score 4):

use single quotations where key have space.

run below .

```
      db.gameItems.find({'weapon name 1':{$exists:1}})
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my OP. Check the edit for correction

Comment: db.gameItems.find({items.'weapon name 1':{$exists:1}})